# Настройка ЧПУ в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу

Не получается правильно настроить ЧПУ.
На сайте есть ссылки вида:

```
 <a href="?menu=portfolio-dizayn-studii" >
 <a href="?menu=portfolio-dizayn-studii/sand-and-sea" >
```

На основе того что приходит в переменной $_GET['menu'] в файле index.php в цикле через include_once подключаются необходимые страницы:

```
    switch($_GET['menu']) {

    case 'portfolio-dizayn-studii-interera-conception':
        include_once("portfolio.php");
    break;
    case 'portfolio-dizayn-studii/sand-and-sea':
        include_once("portfolio/sand-and-sea.php");
    break;
}
```

Попытка настроить ЧПУ выглядела следующим образом,
из ссылок была убрана переменная ?menu:

```
<a href="/portfolio-dizayn-studii" >
<a href="/portfolio-dizayn-studii/sand-and-sea" >
```

И в файле .htaccess были прописаны следующие условия

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```

При переходе по первой ссылке, попадаем на страницу

```
http://site.ru/portfolio-dizayn-studii
```

далее из этой страницы пытаюсь перейти по второй ссылке:

```
<a href="/portfolio-dizayn-studii/sand-and-sea" >
```

то в в адресной строке происходит суммирование адресов и получается вот что:

```
http://site.ru//portfolio-dizayn-studii/portfolio-dizayn-studii
```

и при последующих переходах ссылки прибавляются в адресной строке

Comment: слэши ставьте везде в начале ссылки

Comment: в каком случае?